# Apache Rewrite URL, Works in WAMP, not in LAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a custom MVC app, where in it used `IndexController` naming convention, which I have built on WAMP. Today i tried it to put in to Linux (LAMP).. Strangely, it is giving error "page not found". Can anybody help. I am not good at mod rewrite,

Following is the code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

URL is

> `http://hostname/mvc/incident/add`

Error is  The requested URL /app01/users/public_html/mvc/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: I checked httpd.conf and found that mod_rewrite is enabled

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I solved this issue by using error redirecting functionality. I put following code in my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 403 /~renjith/mvc/index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /~renjith/mvc/index.php
```

and in index.php file i used, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get thr URL with query strings

Answer (score 0):

Try either adding:

```
RewriteBase /mvc/
```

just under the `RewriteEngine on` directive, or add a leading slash to `index.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mvc/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Now the error is The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @Renjith so where *is* `index.php`? And where is your htaccess file?

Comment: inside mvc folder
There are 2 folders and 2 files. 
Folders are 'application' and 'Public'.
Files are .htaccess and index.php

Comment: @Renjith Then change the `RewriteBase` to `/mvc/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `/` before `index.php` and some other stuff. Look at the example I got from Wordpress's one.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is giving new error when i put slash before index.php
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Did you copy the above exactly? If it's located in a subdirectory of the root of the domain, you'll need to change `RewriteBase` to match it.

Comment: And is there an `index.php` file in the root?

Comment: Yes. .inside mvc folder There are 2 folders and 2 files. Folders are 'application' and 'Public'. Files are .htaccess and index.php

Comment: Write the full path to the `index.php` file then in the `.htaccess`. I would really consider putting an `index.php` file in the root that will then call the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

I think that ./htaccess configuration is correct. I solved it simply by adding this directive to my apache2.conf file on debian.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/your_app_folder>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted</Directory>
```

Comment: than a2enmod rewrite & service apache2 restart. That may take some time to work, since the browser may have some old cache. To check it out worth of trying another one.